# Sound engine leaking… is preloading an effect bad practice?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, cocos2d-iphone

In the App Delegate, I am preloading **all** my sound effects and background music.
When testing with Instruments, the tool shows that I am leaking memory, the source being SimpleAudioEngine and a bunch of other classes related to playing sounds. Is `preloadEffect` and `preloadBackgroundMusic` really that bad? How can I fix my memory leaks? Thank you!

Comment: You've been on SO long enough to know not to do ALL CAPS in your question...

Comment: A reported leak and the way you accomplish a task should be two separate things (because you preloadEffect does not mean you should have a memory leak). You need to fix the leaks first, then check the performance of preloading the effects vs loading on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preloading effects is not bad practice, to the contrary. When the sound effect plays for the first time, it is loaded just like with the preload methods. The only thing preloading does is to avoid a stutter or freeze while the effect plays for the first time. For large audio files this can cause the app to pause for a tenth of a second or possibly more.

Comment: Okay! I see. I asked another question about the pause between audio loops. Do you have any suggestion for that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954903/slight-pause-between-sound-loop-with-simple-audio-engine Thanks again!

Comment: When looping background music, there always seems to be a slight pause before the music jumps back to the beginning...