# Slight pause between sound loop with Simple Audio Engine

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, cocos2d-iphone

When playing background music in Simple Audio Engine with `playBackgroundMusic loop:YES`, there seems to be a slight delay before the audio loops back to the beginning and starts over again. Is there any way to prevent this slight pause?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the sound file format that you are bringing in?

Comment: I used to use mp3s, but then I learned that the iPhone/iPod Touch hardware can only decode one mp3 at a time. Thus, I decided to convert ALL my sound files to CAF, even the sound effects. Is this bad?

Comment: Actually no, I found the same thing.  In the game I made, I decided to have the background music as an MP3 (for file size reasons) and the SoundFX come in in an uncompressed format.  Are you doing any compression within the CAF files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pause is actually an artefact of the MP3 encoding/compression algorithms. There are ways to suppress the pause, by doing some math on the 'last frame' of the stream and the first frame. Some software tools exist for that. I ended up using Winamp pro for that purpose, using the built-in LAME encoder.

For more information on this , look [here](http://www.compuphase.com/mp3/mp3loops.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I try The MP3Loop utility and it really helped me. Mp3 files after converting with this utility played as background music with loop without any delay. But it is only for Windows.
http://www.compuphase.com/mp3/mp3loops.htm